# collect2: ld returned 1 exit status error in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

Im getting the error

```
Command /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

and when the full log is opened, the error is more accurately listed as:

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

from this simple Cocoa script:

```
#import "Controller.h"

@implementation Controller

int skillcheck (int level, int modifer, int difficulty)
{
    if (level + modifer >= difficulty)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (level + modifer <= difficulty)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
}

int main ()
{
    skillcheck(10, 2, 10);
}
    
@end
```

the .h file is this:

```
//
//  Controller.h
//
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Controller : NSObject 
{
    int skillcheck;
    int contestcheck;
}

@end
```

and no line was specified that the error came from, does anyone know what the source of this error is, and more importantly, how to fix it?

EDIT:

I removed the class so now I have this:

```
//
//  Controller.m
//
//

#import "Controller.h"

int skillcheck (int level, int modifer, int difficulty)
{
    if (level + modifer >= difficulty)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (level + modifer <= difficulty)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
}

int main ()
{
    skillcheck(10, 2, 10);
}
```

and for the .h file:

```
//
//  Controller.h
//
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

and the log says: (thanks to the guy who said how to open it)

```
Ld build/Debug/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator normal x86_64
cd /Users/anon/Desktop/Calculator
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -L/Users/anon/Desktop/Calculator/build/Debug -F/Users/anon/Desktop/Calculator/build/Debug -filelist /Users/anon/Desktop/Calculator/build/Calculator.build/Debug/Calculator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Calculator.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -framework Cocoa -o /Users/anon/Desktop/Calculator/build/Debug/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator

ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/anon/Desktop/Calculator/build/Calculator.build/Debug/Calculator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Controller.o and /Users/anon/Desktop/Calculator/build/Calculator.build/Debug/Calculator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/anon/Desktop/Calculator/build/Calculator.build/Debug/Calculator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Controller.o and /Users/anon/Desktop/Calculator/build/Calculator.build/Debug/Calculator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o


Command /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is Controller.m in your current target?

Comment: "more accurately"?  not really - can we see more of the log please?

Comment: If you open the build results, to the right of the error should be a small button that looks like many lines of text. Click it, and it will reveal the full text leading up to the failure. That's what we'll need in order to help.

Comment: Yes Controller.m is in my target, I saw that as a suggestion on another thread and checked earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to declare *skillcheck* (which is not required in your case), then it's:

```
int skillcheck (int level, int modifer, int difficulty);
```

and not just:

```
int skillcheck;
```

which would define an *int* variable and not a function returning it. The same is true for *contestcheck*.

I propose you first read somewhat more about Objective-C to get the basics of the language.

**Update:**

It also seems that you have two definitions of *main()*, one in Controller.m and one main.m. You can only have one.

Comment: Ok I fixed that error thanks to you, but now I've got the orginal error back

Comment: What's the full error message now? "Command /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1" and "collect2: ld returned 1 exit status" are just a small part of it. See my update as well.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't at all clear what you are trying to do.   In that example, there is no need for an Objective-C class at all;   it is just a main() function calling a C function and there is no Objective-C involved at all.

From the language of your question and the way that code is written, I'd guess that you are new to Cocoa programming.   You might want to [(re)read this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).

There should be more information barfed up by the compiler/linker.   Make sure you have "all messages" selected in the Build window.

Comment: Yes I am new to Cocoa programming, though not programming in general, I didn't even know there was a class in that script, where is it?

Comment: Go read the linked document.  Then answer the question 'What does the @interface line do?'

Comment: It makes a class, which I have removed now